# Last-modified cache does not show when user has logged-in

Tags: http, caching, coldfusion, http-headers, browser-cache

I am using the `last-modified` HTTP header to help browsers with caching and I have noticed an annoying problem.

If a user visits a page BEFORE he has logged in, then the browser is showing the cached page even after the user logs-in. This means he is unable to see his log-in information (profile pic, notifications etc) in the header until he visits a page on the site he has not visited before.

Because the content of the actual article itself has not changed since his first visit, he is served up the same page even if he logs-in.

I have tried checking to see if the user has just logged-in (using a `SESSION.LoggedIn` variable), and then use the current DateTime for `Last-Modified`, `Expires` and `Cache-Control` to tell the browser to serve up a fresh copy of the page but it doesn't work on the Android browser. It just serves the cached version again. What this means is that the user cannot tell that they have logged-in because their name and other credentials don't appear at the top of the page.

How do I use HTTP header caching effectively and also take care of people visiting the same page as both logged-in and anonymously? The logged-in information sits in the header of the site (just like on SO) so is there a way not to cache the siteheader but the rest of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tool like firebug to see the network traffic for a URL.  You'll notice that it is 'file' objects: html files, javascript files, css files, images, etc.

I don't think that you can cache a div (or other page layout construct) very easily.

It has been a while since I attempted to use the last-modified HTTP header for caching.  I ran into similar problems that you have.  Browser implementation/compatibility wasn't 100%.  I've also used last-modified in an attempt to inform search engine spiders that files have changed.  That didn't work very well either.  Eventually I removed all of my attempts at last-modified caching/hinting and just allow the web server and browsers to deal with it.

Eventually I ended up spending a lot of time optimizing database queries, database indexes, and in a few cases implemented the cachedwithin attribute of cfquery tags.  This attempt at improving site performance has worked better for me.

Comment: Absolutely right. I also noticed that Google wasn't indexing correctly with the last-modified in place. Some speed test tool recommended me to use last-modified so I implemented it blindly but now I've realised its best not to and let the search engines and browsers handle it.